# Loop images on canvas

Tags: java, android, image

I'm trying to loop images in a canvas (Extends view class) to create an animation (Like a GIF One) But it keeps lagging and stuttering my app...

For example :

```
public PlayView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        loadFrames();
        this.context = context;

    }

    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {

    canvas_main = canvas;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.interrupted())
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    time = (time + 1) % 4;
                    image = images[time];
                    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            invalidate();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }).start();

    if (image != null) {
        System.out.println("Image is not null!");
        if (!right_Clicked) {
            canvas_main.drawBitmap(image, width / 2,
                    height - (image.getHeight() + image.getHeight() / 2),
                    paint);

        }


    super.onDraw(canvas_main);

}

void loadFrames() {
        res = getResources();
        images[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image_1);
        images[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image_2);
        images[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image_3);
        images[3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.image_4);
    }
```

How can I manage to loop the images so I can create an animation without lags and stutter?

Comment: You are creating a new thread each time the view is drawn. You are probably creating thousands of threads all trying to draw the images.

Comment: So I'll keep this code as usual but only remove the thread?

Comment: You need the thread for animation. Keep a reference to it and check if null and only create it once.

Comment: Can you give me an example on a code please? I tried what I understood and it did not worked.

Comment: anyway... it is done within the ondraw... it is crazy! You should override the draw method only

Comment: Overriding `onDraw` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it. It is a good idea to kill the thread when you leave the Activity as well.

```
Thread mAnimationThread;

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Not needed canvas_main = canvas;

    if (mAnimationThread == null) {

        mAnimationThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.interrupted())
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        time = (time + 1) % 4;
                        image = images[time];
                        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                invalidate();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });
        mAnimationThread.start();
    }

    if (image != null) {
        if (!right_Clicked) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(image, width / 2,
                    height - (image.getHeight() + image.getHeight() / 2),
                    paint);

        }
    }    
}
```